# how to delete file in java?

Tags: java, video

I want to delete more than one mp4 format files

```
 Path p1 = Paths.get("0.mp4");
 Files.delete(p1);
```

works perfectly fine 
But when i want to delete more than one video ().mp4. 1.mp4, 2.mp4...). It didn't work.

```
 Path p1 = Paths.get(videopath);
 System.out.println(videopath);
 System.out.println(p1);
 Files.delete(p1);
```

videopath is of type String

**Output:**

0.mp4

0.mp4

1.mp4

1.mp4

Logical error is in `Files.delete(p1);`

Comment: If you're asking about an error message that you're receiving, please **show** us the entire message.

Comment: there is no error message. I think it's logical error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+delete+all+files+

Comment: could you print the output surrounded by quotes, so we can verify that the text we are seeing is the entire text being sent to `Paths.get()`? i.e. `System.out.println("'" + p1 + "'");`

Comment: Count the number of files in the path, run a loop for times(lenght). Delete each files individually by passing files based on index

Comment: Files.delete can only delete one file, as it says on the manual page.

Comment: it is not working in a loop

Comment: @akhil gupta I an trying to delete file by function call each time. If I hard code file name. it works but when i pass videopath It did not work

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a variation of the following:

```
for(File file: fileList) file.delete();
```

You can replace `fileList` with something like `dir.listFiles()` for a given directory, or build a list of files.

Comment: Thank you@kogicon.  but I don't want to delete all files. I want to delete specific files one by one.